# How can I get a data from Spring-Security principal?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-security

Now I face with some problems about principal data. Maybe it sounds like a fool. But I'm new to Spring..

I wanted to get some specific data from principal data, but it occured an error, So I cant.

this is my customUserDetails that implement UserDetails.

```
private String id;
    private String pw;
    private String name;
    private String auth;
    private String level;
    private String label;
    private int enabled;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        ArrayList<GrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(auth));
        return authList;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return pw;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled==1?true:false;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getLabel() { return label;} // 4월 19일 동현 추가

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAuth() {
        return auth;
    }
```

And this is principal data I got from console.log

```
CustomUserDetails(id=admin, pw=$2a$10$Z9C0gTGV0weknBvNi4YFY.l41vjrYo4UgO3MlPwgmIn4uDeYlepFq, name=Admin, auth=ROLE_ADMIN, level=null, label=N, enabled=1)
```

I want to extract label value from Principal, so I tried to do this code, but I can't.

```
console.log('${sessionScope.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT.authentication.principal.label}');
```

How can I get 'label' data from principal?

Thank you for your kind support :)

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller or any other bean, autowire user details like

```
public String doSomething(@AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUserDetails userDetails) {
      String label = userDetails.getLabel();
}
```

Comment: I understood how can I get it at Java, but How about Javascript?

Comment: Using jsp or thymeleaf or javascript framework in frontend?

Comment: I use jsp in frontend and also using spring-security now.

Comment: Are you able to do the following:
`
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<sec:authentication property="principal.firstname" /> 
`